# Using Logstash to feed data to multiple elasticsearch "clusters" in output plugins via single config file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder, elastic-stack

I am using ELK and Logstash-forwarder. I am trying to use one logstash instance to send data to multiple elasticsearch `clusters`. My lumberjack output config looks like

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
    cluster => "my-es-cluster"
  }
  elasticsearch {
    cluster => "my-another-cluster"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

When I write the second `elasticsearch` block like that, it floods my logstash logs with

> {:timestamp=>"2015-07-22T00:02:53.274000+0000", :message=>"Lumberjack input: the pipeline is blocked, temporary refusing new connection.", :level=>:warn}

as described in [this Logstash discussion thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nonstop-lumberjack-pipeline-is-blocked-messages/25246). I found only [this old Google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/logstash-users/RVaWXJhvae4) that has a similar case but there is just one mention in the comments that says **it should work**. I checked the documentation for the output plugin but as far as I saw, there is no mention of using same output block in one output plugin conf file.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It's been reported that when using the `cluster` parameter, 
you need to specify the `host` and `port` parameters as well in all your outputs. You should try that.

Comment: I forgot to mention that but I did try it. Adding the `host` parameter in the lower/second elasticsearch block throws exception and logstash stops at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
{:timestamp=>"2015-07-22T00:02:53.274000+0000", :message=>"Lumberjack input: the pipeline is blocked, temporary refusing new connection.", :level=>:warn}
```

This warning is not connected with second cluster in output, I am sure. I have same warning in my Logstash logs, but I am sending only to one cluster. I think this error means, that you have too much messages in your queue, and Logstash will wait some time. Now I am ignoring this warning and my cluster works well. My cluster gets over 120 gb of information per 24 hours.